# Customize the content of Alert Me auto email

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

How to Customise the email content that is received when a user selects Alert Me option in Share point 2013.

I want the user to see a customised text when the library is updated with new files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not customize the OOTB Alert messages.

They are hidden deep down in the bowels of SharePoint,
only blog out there dates from 2007
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

Alternative is to create a SharePoint Designer Workflow which on *every new item* sends an email.
You have full control over all formatting then.

Comment: Thank you Danny. I am completely new to sharepoint. Can you please explain how can i do it?

Comment: [Creating Workflows with SP Designer 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx)